# Windows Installer msi package

Tags: installation, windows-installer

I have a windows installer msi package with the setup.exe bootstrap. Works fine everywhere.
However the client has supposedly uninstalled the application and then tried to run the setup.exe again and gets the following error in the log file: Launching Application. Error: Unable to locate application file 'xyz.msi'.

Now the setup.exe and the msi file are in the same folder. Is this even possible in any scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is looking somewhere daft for your MSI, probably in the MSI cache or System32.

I'd suggest using procmon to capture the file system searches and then search that output for your MSI file name. You'll see it is not found a few times but that will show you where it is looking.

Ryan

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a quick, one-time fix you could also just try to run the .msi directly.